# Getting Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am getting Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," error at but I am unable to locate the place where I am missing "," . Please see the picture below to see the exact line of error.

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cartReducer',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        CART_ADD_ITEM: (state, action) => {
            //checkout action.payload
        },
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [addToCart.pending]: (state) => {
            console.log(state);
            state.loading = true;
        },
        [addToCart.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            console.log(state);
            const item = action.payload;
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find(
                (cartItem) => cartItem.product === item.product
            ); {
                existItem
                    ?
                    (state.cartItems = state.cartItems.map((cartItem) => {
                        return {
                            cartItem.product === existItem.product ? item : cartItem
                        }
                    })) :
                    ((state.loading = false),
                        (state.cartItems = [...state.cartItems, item]));
            }
        },

        [addToCart.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.loading = true;
            state.error = action.payload;
        },
    }
});
```

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79rgb.png)

[Error after removing braces from return statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHtKU.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
return {
    cartItem.product === existItem.product ? item : cartItem
}
```

The above statement is wrong, you don't need `{}` there. write it in a single line, like this:

```
return cartItem.product === existItem.product ? item : cartItem;
```

Comment: By doing that i get this error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: That error could be from the line `{  existItem` because you're not returning anything there. if it's from `return cartItem.product === existItem.product ? item: cartItem;` you can change it to if/else and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: I have updated picture of second error please check it

Comment: as I explained above, in line no 42, you're returning nothing, so you have an error, it expects you to return something.

Comment: I am unable to understand how to return anything in conditional rendering

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do in your code, but if you're using an expression statement then it expects you to either return something or store the result in a variable using the assignment operator(=), but if your code doesn't require any return or assignment then you need to use if/else statement instead of using the conditional expression, or you could just disable eslint for that line, it's up to your logic what you're trying to do there.